# What is the most fundamental continuous function in calculus after a constant (totally straight) line?

Tags: calculus, functions

What would be to teach in most countries and education systems?

(Taught before "high education frames", i.e. before doing bachelor of arts in mathematics).

Comment: I think that this question might profit from additional information. Without context I am not sure whether I fully understand what kind of answer would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

The linear function is a pretty good first example: they are very fundamental and everything is simple.
But rather than think in terms of the most fundamental thing to come next, I would encourage you to think in terms of typical examples that show the breadth of the concept.

- Linear function
- Polynomial of maybe second degree (not linear, but still fairly familiar)
- Constant function (too elementary a case for students to understand easily, and valuable due to that)
- Absolute value (or some other piecewise defined function)
- Square root (not defined everywhere)
- Maybe $x^{-1}$ (if you want to get tricky)

For signal processing you might go more in the direction of sine and cosine as simple examples and in general use more periodic examples.

Comment: With all niceness I did not ask for any encouragement, just for an example (and it's not even about mere mathematics but about signal processing); I had a mistake asking for just one example because I would agree that constant function (100% straight line) is too simple and I need the thing coming just above it in the line so there should be just two examples. I should edit the question to explain and I think it would be good if you will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I also disagree with `Constant function (too simple a case, causes problems)` because I believe that this function should be the very first one to teach when introducing the "continuous" concept (at least as taught for signal processing).

Comment: Edited. You might want to add something about signal processing into the question.

Comment: The most elementary is the most elementary (as you know). I think that a constant line, and then sine, are enough for giving an elementary firstmost glimpse into signal processing (when explaining a term such as "continuous").

Comment: @chichorozov, for signal processing, you could also discuss even and odd functions.

Comment: @chichorozov Since you seem to already know the answer you want to get, you should answer the question yourself. It is okay to do.

Comment: @Tommi you already published an answer from which I got the (personal) idea that sine wave is the best example to be taught right after a constant wave to explain the "continuous" concept; I also mean to suggest you to edit the answer a bit to keep only constant line and sine wave (and remove the claim that a constant line is "too simple"), but if you don't want to, than it's not my issue and I don't have anything else to say on the matter.

Comment: @chichorozov minor edit to clarify

Answer (score 1):

The category-theorist in me would argue the most fundamental function is the identity function, so $f(x)=x$ might be a good one to go to next.

I say this one because, when you really start diving down into what "fundamental" is, the existence of an identity mapping is really key to a lot of structures.  In particular, categories.  And, of course, its a dirt simple function, which is probably what you're going for.

Of course this being said, the constant function and identity function can also be tricky first functions because they are *so* simple that it's hard to get any feel for functions at all with them.